# Computing the elevation angle of a GPS satellite with respect to the given receiver location

Tags: elevation, satellite, angles, gps

can anyone source an explicit formula for calculating the elevation angle for a GPS satellite as seen from a receiver. I can't seem to find one. Even a text reference would be great. I couldn't quite find anything posted already that does the same thing.

I'm also looking for something similar for calculating elevation but for Glonass satellites as well.

Answer (score 3):

Is the GNSS receiver providing NMEA data? If so, is the GSV sentence provided? If so, the elevation in degrees is provided in that specific sentence.

http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gsv

Answer (score 2):

I found this image that hints at the formula:
[image]

(the original image is at http://help.agi.com/stk/Content/stk/images/xconstraints-1.gif.pagespeed.ic.YpPTo2N_zh.png)